# Generated APK from keystore file, but does not change project

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-keystore

So I have a client that has sent me a keystore file and told me that is how I will get the APK. I followed the directions for generating an APK from a keystore here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release

What am I missing here? Why am I still loading the default blank project I am trying to load? Have I overwritten something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you miss understood the concept of a keystore .
the keystore is used along with a password to sign  an apk or aab of an existing project.
so if a client sent you a keystore how do you expect to get an apk from the keystore file ? it doesn't contain an apk in it .

Comment: I knew I wasn't crazy!! Thank you so much.